# Handling objects in a tile-based system that are bigger than 1 tile

Tags: c#, grid-layout

I have a twodimensional int array which stores blocks of different colors, they're based on the int value so for example 1 = blue and 2 = green.

I have no issues so far where everything is just single tiles but I can't seem to solve my problem when I come to bigger tiles. The point is that in my game whenever 4 or more blocks (of the same color) come together they form a bigger block. So a 2x2 block of blue pieces for example. How would I go around to handle that? I can't seem to come up with a solution, not even an inefficient one. I've thought of making a twodimensional "block" array instead that would contain the color value and a "isinblock" bool to specify that it's a part of a bigger block but I can't seem to think of a solution afterwards.

An example might clarify what I mean, in this situation:

```
int[][] blockGrid = {{0, 0, 0, 0},
                     {0, 0, 0, 0},
                     {0, 0, 0, 0},
                     {0, 1, 0, 0}  };
```

there is no issue. I go through the array and draw/update the tile like normally.
Here however:

```
int[][] blockGrid = {{0, 0, 0, 0},
                     {0, 0, 0, 0},
                     {0, 1, 1, 0},
                     {0, 1, 1, 0}  };
```

here it gets more complicated for me. Because soar code-wise these are just 4 different tiles, but I want to "fuse" them into one 2x2 block, it has different properties such as both 2 spaces underneath need to be free for it to move downwards, a higher score is rewarded when it is cleared and has a different sprite. I will also later need to find any matching colors of that block "around" it(horizontally and vertically) but that won't be an issue I imagine, will be very similar to how I do it for a single block unless the method of implementing the 2x2 + block is very different from my current approach. 
I'd also like to add that this should work not only for 2x2's but up to 5x5's etc so I'm looking for a generic case scenario of fixing this.

Thank you in advance, I hope I was clear enough with explaining my problem here.

Comment: Assume that you can create an array BlockIds, matrix of int parallel to your Tiles array and that the values of this array specify a unique Id identifying the block composed of "contiguous" tiles with same color. Would this help ? In other words, your initial array stores the color of the tile and the new array indicates which block contains the tile.

Comment: @Graffito So you suggest I create another array which will hold different unique ID's which I can use to save the data of all current blocks while keeping the old one that would just save the data for the old array which would just be which color a tile is? I'll tinker around with my code and see if I can get that to work somehow. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: My suggestion may be an intermediate state from which you can build a list of blocks where each block is list of Tiles referenced by there (x,y) coordinates.